# What is the equivalent of magnify function in a Fujiffilm xt20 camera?

Tags: fujifilm, fujifilm-x-t20

As showcased in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHSmT5I3vP0), there is a button on the Canon camera (Canon 5DS R) which allows the user to zoom into a live view on LCD.

[image: Magnify button in circle]

I have highlighted the button in a screen grab of the video above. When the user presses the magnify button, the area in the rectangle will occupy the full area of the LCD, as in the following:

[image: Magnify button effect]

Is there an equavalent function in Fujifilm Xt20?

Answer (score 5):

Focus assist should be available when pressing the button on the rear command dial.

> Focus Zoom If ON is selected for AF/MF SETTING > FOCUS CHECK, the
>   camera will automatically zoom in on the selected focus area when the
>   focus ring is rotated.
>
> If STANDARD or FOCUS PEAK HIGHLIGHT is selected for AF/MF SETTING > MF
>   ASSIST, zoom can be adjusted by rotating the rear command dial.